# Rails 3 and Strange Accept Headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Rails 3 site is getting hit by crawlers with strange accept headers, trigger exceptions as like

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in home#show
```

Here are some of the accept headers causing issues

```
text/*
application/jxw
*/*;q=0.1
```

In these cases, this is being interpreted as the format for the request, and as such, causing the missing template error. I don't really care what I return to these crawlers, but just want to avoid the exceptions.

Comment: Seems this will be fixed in Rails 3.0.4, see https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/6022-content-negotiation-fails-for-some-headers-regression - there is also a patch in that ticket.

Comment: This appears to be resolved in Rails 3.1. Discussion here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/701

Answer (score 7):

You could rescue from exception like this in your application controller and render the HTML template instead:

```
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, :with => :render_html

  def render_html
    if not request.format == "html" and Rails.env.production?
      render :format => "html"
    else
      raise ActionView::MissingTemplate
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wait what? `not request.format == "html"`? Did you mean `request.format != "html"?

Comment: Is there a good way to make requests in my local environment to simulate the issue in question? I'd like to try this fix out but I want to be able to make sure it's working for us before deploying it to production.

Comment: Also, accept an exception parameter and raise that, e.g., `def render_html(exception) ... raise exception`

Comment: @blim8183 
remove `and Rails.env.production?`,
`curl -H "Accept: */*;" -v http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 1):

Because SO prevents adding comments until I have 50 reputation, I must submit a new answer to reply to Ryan Bigg's question in the comments.

`not request.format == "html"` is more or less the same thing as `request.format != "html"`. `and`, `or` and `not` are logically identical to `&&`, `||` and `!` - however, they have much lower precedence. So, in this example, the `==` operator evaluates before the `not` operator, such that it produces the same result as using `!=`.

Comment: Sure, but Ryan most likely meant that the way that `not foo == bar` is worded makes it much harder to parse (for a human) than `foo != bar`.