# Ruby on Rails and strange HTTP_ACCEPT header from PSP

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby on Rails app (3.1rc4) and I am constantly getting a couple of exceptions each day with the same user agent (Mozilla/4.0 (PSP (PlayStation Portable); 2.00)). Exception:

```
A ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in home#index:
Missing template home/index, application/index with {:formats=>["*/*;q=0.01"], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb]}. Searched in:
"/var/www/releases/20110721144523/app/views"
```

I do have app/views/home/index.html.erb, but looks like it tries to find a file for a very strange request format "*/*;q=0.01".

HTTP Header:

```
 * HTTP_ACCEPT                               : */*;q=0.01
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4905464/811653 I use this, it works very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem, see the [ticket](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/701%20ticket) on Github.

You can choose to render HTML explicitly; just write `render "index.html"` instead of `render`. This will return HTML instead of a 406 though. I hope there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4176
You can fix it with respond_to and respond_with methods in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have monkey patched this in Rails 3.0.x using middleware fix like:

```
class FixHttpAcceptHeader
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    case env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
      when 'text/*', '*/*' # add others as needed
        env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'text/html'
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

in application.rb

```
config.middleware.use "FixHttpAcceptHeader"
```

tested with this ruby script (found this script somewhere online but don't recall where...)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request["Accept"] = "text/*"

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```