# Rails request with HTTP_ACCEPT header of `: */*`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my rails app threw an exception because of a `ActionView::MissingTemplate`-exception. This was because a request had a http header `ACCEPT` with the value `: */*`. The app couldn't find a template for this format (which is what I expect to happen). The user agent was set to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36`.

I'm curious (and a little concerned) about what this means. Is this a problem with rails, a problem with my app, or an attack vector? I've seen answers to similar questions (e.g. [Ruby on Rails and strange HTTP_ACCEPT header from PSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778368/ruby-on-rails-and-strange-http-accept-header-from-psp)) which proposed to rescue these exception and answer with the format set to HTML. However, before using this approach I'd like to now if `: */*` is an acceptable value for `ACCEPT`, and which browser would set it like that.

I'm on Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same problem on a production app. I keep getting some request with `: */*` accept header. In my errbit instance it shows the following browsers: **Chrome 27.0.1453.116** (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36)
**Internet Explorer 7.0** (Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0))
**Explore** (Explore 6.0). Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: I asked on the rails issue tracker (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11704), and it seems this header is invalid according to the spec. You can either ignore these invalid headers, or you rescue them using a middleware and set the format to html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known, and ancient, bug in Rails' MIME type parser - see [this bug report](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4127) for details. Workarounds exist, but a fix would be preferable!

Comment: Thanks, there is a lot of interesting information in the bug report, plus some possible workarounds. I decided to do nothing about it, because it only happened once for me.

Comment: Rescuing with `request.format = "html"` is a good solution - much preferable to showing an error page!

Comment: I think it's fixed in latest Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have wrong order in `respond_to` block, try to add the one with template as first. For example if you want `html` as default:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```