# Missing template error in Rails 4 when requesting format */*;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, format, actionview

I've been seeing these errors for a long time but haven't found an issue:

`ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["*/*;"]}`

The user agent is always MSIE6 (which is part of the reason I gave up earlier).

To reproduce: `curl -H "Accept: */*;" -I http://localhost:5000`

Any one knows how to fix?

**EDIT**

`curl -H "Accept: */*" -I http://localhost:5000` works. It doesn't work only when the format is set as `*/*;` (notice the semi-colon).

**UPDATE**

I tried modifying `Mime:ALL` as suggested in the comments but wasn't able to have it accept both `*/*` and `*/*;` at the same time. A solution I see is monkey-patching how requests are handled when no or malformed mime types are present, but I'm unsure how. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22992640/1389981) provides a clue but I still don't have one.

**MORE UPDATE**

I'm still seeing these errors and more. A new one is with `:formats=>["hc/url;*/*"]` (Firefox). I'm so surprised this isn't hitting anyone else, I don't think I have anything specific in my code that would lead to uncommon errors.

Comment: set root in `routes.rb` as `root "pages#home"`

Comment: Rails maps `"*/*" => :all` , I'm not sure how but you could probably coerce treating :all as a :html request

Comment: All my routes are correctly set Rajarshi. Actually the issue is subtle. `*/*` works, `*/*;` doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking that you could fix this by registering a mime type `Mime::Type.register "*/*;", :all`. Or possibly Mime::ALL = Mime::Type.new("*/*", :all, ['*/*;']).  I think you would need to do this in an initializer. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f6f43338f7e4d3a3fe5ad86d024007ee95a7389/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb

Comment: It worked! Redefining Mime::ALL throws a warning so the register is probably best. You should put that in an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Nevermind, both version throw a warning. At least it properly routes requests..

Comment: Update: turns out `*/*` stopped working after my update, simply because it was overriden, so very bad idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4905464/811653 I use this, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

*gregkare* just posted a fix on [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4127#issuecomment-113147026).

```
DEFAULT_RESPONSE_FORMAT = :html  
before_filter :set_default_response_format

def set_default_response_format
  request.format = DEFAULT_RESPONSE_FORMAT if request.format.to_sym.nil?
end
```

Not exactly sure about side effects but seems to work great for now.